# Twitter API: Getting Data for Analytics

Tags: python, twitter

I am looking to create a simple graph showing 2 numbers of time for my personal twitter. They are:

1. Number of followers per day
2. Number of mentions per day

From my research so far, the search API does not provide a date so I am not about to do a `GROUP BY`. The only way I can have access to dates is through the OAuth Api but that requires interaction from the end user which I am trying to avoid.

Can someone point me in the right direction in order to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a cron to record the data daily.

However, you can query the mentions using the search api with a untill tag. Which should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

We can although use the search api to fetch mentions but there is a limit in it.
At a given point of time you can only fetch 200 mentions.

Any one knows how to get total mentions count?